# Garbage-collecting jobject returned from JNI to Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

As stated in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913440/jni-environment-pointer-in-a-static-c-object-and-calling-a-java-function-takin/35950745#35950745),

> All jobjects created inside a JNI method are local references by default. Whenever a JNI method returns, all local references are automatically released.

In the same time,

> When a global reference is no longer needed, it should be deleted by DeleteGlobalRef, otherwise referenced object will never be garbage-collected.

So, in order to return a jobject from JNI back to Java, we need global reference. But in the same time, how can we make it to be eventually garbage-collected on Java side, if DeleteGlobalRef cannot be called from there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning local reference created by JNI from a native method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581639/returning-local-reference-created-by-jni-from-a-native-method)

Comment: _"in order to return a jobject from JNI back to Java, we need global reference"_. No. See the middle part of the answer to the question I linked to for an explanation. The answer you linked to isn't referring to returning Java objects from native code to Java - it's referring to creating a Java object in native code and using it in subsequent calls to native code from Java.

Comment: Don't confuse a reference with the object. Just like any returned object on the Java side, if the caller keeps a reference, it won't be collected. In other words, a return transfers a reference. It's up to the caller how long that reference is held.